# Python, Bokeh - my button won't do ANYTHING

Tags: python, bokeh

Python 3.6 and Bokeh 0.12.16.

No matter what I change the body of the onclick() function to - it doesn't do anything! I can't even verify if it's being called or not.

```
button = Button(label='Update', button_type='primary')
button.on_click(onclick)

p = Paragraph(text='aaaaaaa',
width=200, height=100)

def onclick():
    plot_layout.children[2]=Paragraph(text="test")
    show(plot_layout)

plot_layout = layout([Laser_Dropdown,Section_Dropdown,p,button])

output_file("test.html")
show(plot_layout)
```

Comment: Did you try this in a simple script, without a GUI to confirm that it is actually working?

Comment: There are so many mistakes in your code.. to much to mention them all. Perhaps try first replicating some examples on the bokeh site. In any case (1) when you want to use the onclick() function as you do you need to declare this function before you call it (2) for truly dynamic pages you need to work with the bokeh server and the curdoc() method instead of the show()

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in your code.. to much to mention them all. First try this:
save the below script in a file script.py and
open a cmd in the directory where you saved the file and run "bokeh serve script.py --show'

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def onclick():
    print('somebody clicked the button and this can be read in the bokeh console')
button = Button(label='Update', button_type='primary')
button.on_click(onclick)

curdoc().add_root(button)
```